# jquery menu accordion styling issue

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I posted the code into a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLNXa/, basically i want the whole menu to be a block ie if you expand level 1, i don't want there to be a 15px gap to the left of level 2 with level 2 still remaining indented. (the white space filled in with red and the two black borders:
what is currently is:

[image]

what i want it to look like:

[image]

on my website however, instead of colours there is a dynamic background image ie:

[image]

so im not sure if  classing the indent each time would work...

and the actual menu with the background image:
http://couch.betelnutmedia.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/kLNXa/2/)

I have just added this code to your css bottom

```
// Added Code
    .accordion li{ padding-left:0px;} 
.accordion li a{padding-left:15px; display:block } 
.accordion li ul li a{padding-left:30px;background-position:15px 50% !important;} 
.accordion li ul li ul li a {padding-left: 45px; background-position:30px 50% !important;} 
.accordion li ul li ul li ul li a {padding-left: 60px; background-position:45px 50% !important;}

​
```

but if you have dynamic/variable level  then you should go for jQuery

Comment: i was trying to avoid doing this, as i would have to redo the whole dynamic part of the code in a language I'm not very comfortable in. http://i.imgur.com/iY39F.jpg

Comment: yeh :( well 4 levels and then in some cases 3

Comment: if menu levels limited to 3 or 4 then you can use the above mention css solution. give it a try use the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/kLNXa/2/) for reference

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15655/discussion-between-champ-and-user1448093)